# trouble creating sandbox in groovy

Tags: ros, rosws, roscd, ros-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to install groovy on a 64 bit HP G62 running Ubuntu 12.04. Followed installation instructions up to 4.2 Creating a sandbox directory for new packages.

Under 4.1 Creating a new workspace, I changed out
rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte
to
rosws init ~/groovy_workspace /opt/ros/groovy

$echo ROS_PACKAGE_PATH returned /opt/ros/groovy/share:/opt/ros/groovy/stacks

I checked in the home folder and groovy_workspace was indeed created. Sandbox folder was created in the groovy_workspace folder. Thinking it odd that my package path didn't match, I continued on to the the tutorials to see what would happen.

Had no problems until I got to the point where it tells you to run roscd by itself.

this is what I got:
No ROS_WORKSPACE set.  Please set ROS_WORKSPACE to use roscd with no arguments.

tried the whole procedure again but as written in the wiki, not substituting groovy for fuerte, same result. (fuerte_workspace created, sandbox inside, but all else exactly the same). Not sure what I'm doing wrong, would appreciate some guidance.

regards, Richard

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54523/trouble-creating-sandbox-in-groovy/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like a bug. I tried to replicate the problem and can confirm the same behaviour.

Seems the issue is somewhere in `setup.sh` and/or in the files it implicitly sources. It unsets the `ROS_WORKSPACE` variable exported at the beginning. Even if you specify `ROS_WORKSPACE` by hand it will be deleted after sourcing the `setup.bash`.

To make `roscd` work without arguments I can suggest you to set `ROS_WORKSPACE` explicitly in your `.bashrc` **after** the line that sources the relevant setup file.

**EDIT:** opened a [ticket](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/356).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is a bug in rosinstall, where ROS_WORKSPACE needs to be set after it has been unset by the catkin setup.sh. https://github.com/vcstools/rosinstall/issues/57
You can as a workaround also export ROS_WORKSPACE again at the bottom of the setup.sh in your rosbuild workspace.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1